# Fastboot Kernel Install

Tags: kernel

I want to install Arrow OS with OrangeFox.  I understood the installation step, but I want to install the KVM opened kernel.  I have it in the form of boot.img file and I install it with the `fastboot flash boot boot.img` command.  How can I install it on Arrow OS?

My Phone: Redmi Note 10S (Secret)
Note: This device uses A/B

Comment: ask maintainer of kernel to provide anykernel3 zip

Comment: So, can it be installed as .img with OrangeFox?  Or what happens if I install the .img file via Fastboot?

Comment: please clarify what is your understanding of kernel, boot and .img file. boot partition typically contains kernel + ramdisk + dtb. .img files can have different formats. maybe provide the link to whatever "KVM opened kernel"?

Comment: I just uploaded it to my own Google Drive account: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11UjxXIXq66L2oLLyBGUW7H-KRGyWZYpw/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: sorry that's of no use to me. what I meant is link to origin of that kernel (thread/tutorial/changelog etc) not the file itself. If you are the author I recommend to read about anykernel3, and recommend not to share binary only, without any source code (which is violating GPL licence)